# application error, can't linked and put data to another columns, need help to complete code

Tags: vba, excel

when i do word count, the new sheet which is created, column A cells  full filled with the " all word " and macro get stop with error, i need code which auto changes the column when privious get column get full, help me out with this... means the data which word count and frequency should be generate is large and due to large data... column cells gets full and error occurs.... i tried copying and shifting the new generated "all words " data but is doesn't work properly.. i need some trick code that automatically put all the data... into new columns... following is code used for word count...........

```
Sub MakeWordList()
    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WordListSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PuncChars As Variant, x As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim wordCnt As Long
    Dim AllWords As Range
    Dim PC As PivotCache
    Dim PT As PivotTable

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set InputSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set WordListSheet = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Sheets.count))
    WordListSheet.Range("A1:B1") = "All Words"
    WordListSheet.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
    InputSheet.Activate
    wordCnt = 2
    PuncChars = Array(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", "-", "--", "---", "@", "`", _
       "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", " - ", "_", "--", "+", "<", ">", "BLANK", _
        "=", "~", "/", "\", "{", "}", "[", "]", """", "?", "*", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
            r = 1


'   Loop until blank cell is encountered
    Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
'       covert to UPPERCASE
        txt = UCase(Cells(r, 1))
'       Remove punctuation
        For i = 0 To UBound(PuncChars)
            txt = Replace(txt, PuncChars(i), "")
        Next i
'       Remove excess spaces
        txt = WorksheetFunction.Trim(txt)
'       Extract the words
        x = Split(txt)
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)
            WordListSheet.Cells(wordCnt, 1) = x(i)
            wordCnt = wordCnt + 1
        Next i
    r = r + 1
    Loop

'   Create pivot table
    WordListSheet.Activate
    Set AllWords = Range("A1:B1").CurrentRegion
    Set PC = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add _
        (SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=AllWords)
    Set PT = PC.CreatePivotTable _
        (TableDestination:=Range("D1"), _
        TableName:="PivotTable1")
    With PT
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("All Words")
        .PivotFields("All Words").Orientation = xlRowField
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare another variable:

```
Dim OutClm as long
```

Then change you loop to this:

```
    OutClm = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        if wordCnt > WordListSheet.Rows.Count Then
            OutClm = OutClm + 1
            wordcnt = 1
        End If
        WordListSheet.Cells(wordCnt, OutClm) = x(i)
        wordCnt = wordCnt + 1
    Next i
```